# 2 mobile having same mac addresses are connecting to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have tp link router, and I have set wireless password on it, and also I have set Mac Filtering, so that only selected devices can connect to my router, but I don't know how someone is hacking into my router and he is hacking my password and also he has changed his mac address of his cell phone to the same mac address of my cell phone. Now he is using my wifi and I cannot block him because he is using same mac address, when I am connected to my wifi he is connected too, but only one mac address is showing on router statistics, because 2 mobiles are on same mac address, could you please tell me how do i block him and what do i do to prevent from hacking ?

now in that case what do i do ? I don't know how to secure my wifi, if I change the password then in matter of seconds he comes known to the password.

Comment: How do you know that there is another person is using your wifi?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Seems like an entirely reasonable question to me.

Comment: I would note that if 2 devices with the same mac address are connected at the same time this is going to cause very broken and problematic Internet for both of them.

Comment: What state/country are you in?  In addition to the technical mitigations (which should absolutely be your first line of defense), you may be able to lay a charge against him or take civil action.

Answer (score 3):

If someone really is hacking your WiFi, do the following:

Set a new and secure WPA2-passphrase. MAC-Address filters are insecure and can easily be bypassed.

Comment: +1  - If this password becomes known then its either because its not strong enough (probable) or the router is broken.   You may want to flash the router with new firmware.   Also, get rid of MAC Filtering.